# Why aggregate price improvement by size of order in shares and not size of order in value?

Tags: united-states, trading, commission

As explained in https://www.stockbrokers.com/guides/order-execution ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180114052505/https://www.stockbrokers.com/guides/order-execution)), the information present in SEC Rule 606 reports don't allow to compare the order execution quality between brokers. As a result, the  Financial Information Forum (FIF) has created a template that allows compare price improvement (= difference between price you eventually obtained vs. the price you saw quoted when you passed the order) between brokers: online brokers that participate voluntarily share their execution quality data in an agreed upon format that continues to evolve.

Here is an excerpt of [Fidelity Brokerage Services LLC's 2017 Q3 report](https://www.fidelity.com/bin-public/060_www_fidelity_com/documents/FIF-FBS-retail-execution-quality-stats.pdf) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180115013330/https://www.fidelity.com/bin-public/060_www_fidelity_com/documents/FIF-FBS-retail-execution-quality-stats.pdf)) following FIF's template:

[image]

Why aggregate price improvement by size of order in shares and not size of order in value (i.e., number of shares * price of a share)? I would have guessed that the price improvement is more correlated with the value of order than with the number of shares.

Comment: How are you determining that this is the case from the data above?

Comment: @CraigW I don't; it's just a guess, which could be incorrect. I'm looking for data confirming or infirming it.

Comment: It is not clear to me what the question is. If possible could you elaborate more on the last paragraph.

Comment: @Dheer did you understand "Why aggregate price improvement by size of order in shares and not size of order in value (i.e., number of shares * price of a share)?" or is it unclear?

Comment: Not very clear. I don't see aggregate price improvements by size of order in shares; in fact the price has not improved. I don't see data for order in value.

Comment: @Dheer In the 2 tables, the column "order size range" indicate the size of order in shares. The first group is 1-99, the second group is 100-499, and so on. For the first group 1-99, the "average saving per order" is 0.75 USD for the S&P 500 stocks. I wonder why the grouped by number of shares (e.g., between 1 and 99), and not by value of the order.

Comment: @Downvoters: please explain your vote, I would be happy to improve the question.

Answer (score 3):

> Referring to comment, why the table is depicting order size in number of shares and value of shares.

What is being depicted is once an limit order is placed; at or better ... how is it routed by the broker. An indirect measure is how may times the order get fulfilled at better rate and what is the gain. So if you have placed order for "X" stock quantity between 1 to 99; could be 10, 20 or 50 etc ... The second column says the average quantity for orders between 1 - 99 is 31 shares [this could be of "X" or anything]. Next column indicates how got fulfilled and how got filled at better rate than specified by the limit order; 96.2% in this case.

The average savings is notional; In this case 0.68 for a lot size of 31, i.e. approx 0.02 cents better per share.

Whether the order are filled at Limit or better is a function of liquidity in the market and the ability of broker to place the orders fast [as there is price and time priority for matching]. Some brokers if they are slow at placing the orders, then market would have moved and the limit order does not get filled.

On larger limit orders quantity, the queue depth would mean that less orders will be fulfilled and the price saved per share would be less as the matching will be against multiple orders sitting to be matched.

All the above is more of a function of order quantity rather than per share price of any item. That is what is depicted in the table.